# Index Scan with PROBE instead of an Index Seek

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

I have a query that looks like this:

```
--Updated To remove Distinct per Aaron Bertrand's suggestion in the comments
SELECT  TOP 100 ord.OrderId
FROM    Customer cust
        JOIN CustomerOrder ord
            ON ord.CustomerId = cust.CustomerId
WHERE   cust.FirstName LIKE (@firstName + '%')                
ORDER BY ord.CreatedWhen DESC
```

And I have an index like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyIndex] ON CustomerOrder
(
    OrderId DESC,
    CustomerId DESC,
    CreatedWhen Desc
)
GO
```

When I run my query, the index gets used, but it is an index scan.  And it gives this message:

> PROBE([Bitmap1011],[MyDatabase].[order].[CustomerOrder].[OrderId] as [ord].[OrderId],N'[IN ROW]')

The output list consists of the OrderId and CreatedWhen.

**What is this PROBE doing and why I don't get an Index Seek?**

UPDATE:

The FirstName column on the Customer table does have an index that is being used in an IndexSeek.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Customer_FirstName] ON Customer
(
    [FirstName] ASC
)
GO
```

Comment: Why do you need distinct? Can you really two have different orders with the same id and created date? You could also make the NC index unique... though isn't there a clustered index that would already facilitate this?

Comment: Also why do you expect to get a seek on this index, when your where clause is filtering on a column not even covered by this index (never mind the leading column)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I have another index on the FirstName that is being used.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I really need the newest 100 orders that match the name.  I originally had this with a `group by ord.OrderId` (instead of distinct) and `order by Max(ord.CreatedWhen) desc`  I was playing with this to see if I could get a better plan.  (They ended up being about the same.)

Comment: Try using a semi-join (SELECT FROM CustomerOrder WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customer)). Anyway still don't understand how distinct or group by can possibly eliminate duplicates here. Could be other things going on here too - parameter sniffing, maybe you got a plan for `Smith` that's trying to be used for `Quixote`. Try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query. Post the actual post-execution plan somewhere so we can take a look and not have to guess through your word problems. Also do you really identify customers by `John%`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Only very rarely do we identify customers by name.  But it can happen.  (If the customer sends in incomplete paperwork that only has a name on it.)  As for the group by.  I can't believe I did not catch that.  THANK YOU!.  I am going to remove the distinct/group by.  (However, I still get the PROBE without it.)

Comment: Post the whole query plan.  It has to deal with WHERE cust.FirstName LIKE (@firstName + '%')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that an Index Scan gets used is because your WHERE clause predicate is based on CustomerId, but it appears as the **SECOND** column in the list of columns in your non-clustered index [IX_MyIndex].

If you want an Index **Seek** to be performed, you would need to specify a new non-clustered index just on column CustomerId.

And that would essentially be a good practice - have two separate NC indices for OrderId and CustomerId. So when you join Customer and CustomerOrder tables, it will use the NC Index for CustomerId, and when you join Order and CustomerOrder tables, it will use the NC index for OrderId.

Refer to this [article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208733/clustered-index-scan-in-query-with-non-clustered-index-filter) to read more about the difference between a multi-column non-clustered index (which you currently have) and multiple non-clustered indexes (which I proposed using).

**[UPDATE]**

But creating separate non-clustered indexes is not sufficient in getting an Index Seek everytime. That will depend on the columns being selected in the query, and the size of the data being read - based on that the query optimizer will accordingly make a decision on whether to use an Index Seek or an Index Scan. See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244093/129515) for more information.

**[UPDATE Feb 8, 2021]**

At a high-level, the PROBE function in question would essentially try to verify whether the CustomerOrder.OrderId column value is present in the Customer table. This is achieved internally through the using of bitmaps and hash keys, and you can read in detail about it [here](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2018/05/plansplaining-part-5-bitmaps/).

Note that a PROBE is not specific to an Index Scan or an Index Seek. It is simply a function that is utilized for verifying matches (based on a certain hash keyed column(s)) between two tables in a join.

Comment: This does not answer the question "what is this PROBE doing", which is especially a bummer because it is the first result when searching for "index scan with probe" on Google.

Comment: See updated answer for details on what the PROBE is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple reason: your `FirstName` column isn't in the index. It must scan every row to see if the row matches the pattern you want.

Comment: FirstName is on a different table (and it has an index on that table).

Comment: Then what is the definition of that second index?

Comment: I did not think it was relevant, so I left it out.  But I just added it to the question.